# url_decode64 binary serialization to string

Tags: elixir

I am currently trying to decode some base64 CDATA from Youtube Comments. It seems to decode it into a binary fine, but not sure how to convert it to a string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><comments><![CDATA[EAEYACCQTg==]]></comments></root>
```

And in elixir

```
iex> Base.url_decode64!("EAEYACCQTg==")    
<<16, 1, 24, 0, 32, 144, 78>>
```

And if I try to toss it into a utf8 string, it doesn't match.

```
iex> <<x::utf8>> = Base.url_decode64!("EAEYACCQTg==")
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: <<16, 1, 24, 0, 32, 144, 78>>
```

Comment: Strings in Elixir _are_ binaries, so there's no conversion necessary here. For example, `<<65, 66, 67>>` is exactly the same as `"ABC"`, it's just a matter of Elixir pretty printing it for you. When a binary only contains valid codepoints it will be printed as string, otherwise it will be printed as a "raw" binary. The point is: the bytes you have decoded are not a valid string, for example strings cannot contain `0` bytes. Probably there's another level of encoding involved here. Do you happen to know what the result should exactly look like?

Comment: I think that's my problem, its not really a string representation. I am trying to decode it from their site directly, and not through an API. Not sure of the actual encoding of the data is.

Comment: Do you know what the expected output is? That would make it much easier to figure out the necessary steps for decoding.

Comment: This representation is when no new comments are present. I was imagining it would be a JSON or maybe BSON representation? http://pastebin.com/Q7qUpM3f is a larger example showing multiple new comments. When I parse it in python, it comes out like: http://pastebin.com/9jhEtqpw

Comment: Yeah looks like some binary serialization format. I hear Google uses Protobuf in some places, but I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the encoded value you're using is the problem:

```
iex(1)> Base.url_decode64!("EAEYACCQTg==") |> String.valid?
false
iex(2)> <<104, 101, 197, 130, 197, 130, 111>> |> String.valid?
true
iex(3)> IO.puts "The string is #{<<104, 101, 197, 130, 197, 130, 111>>}"
The string is hełło
:ok
```

If the decoded string was valid you'd get a string out of the box as a return value:

```
iex(4)> Base.encode64("foobar")
"Zm9vYmFy"
iex(5)> Base.url_decode64!("Zm9vYmFy")
"foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your match pattern is for a single utf-8 character, not a string, however while there is no match pattern for an arbitrary length utf-8 string, you can recursively parse the result binary character by character using that pattern to extract a utf-8 string.

Comment: Thanks Bitwalker. Always a good help. This was helpful, didn't consider it to only get 1 bit at a time.